# Socket that constantly listens

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

so i've searched for about 2 weeks for this , and i can't find any legit answer.

I have two projects , one is a server and the other one is a client.

I've only managed to make a client console application that sends data only ONCE to the server and then exits. Nothing else.

So how can i make a client that sends a string from a textbox to a server over the network , and the server CONSTANTLY listens . ALWAYS listens . Does not only listen once and finish the program but waits for a connection and when a connection is made , the server accepts the client's string , writes the string or writes in a textbox , AND instantly goes back to listening for a connecion .

I'm using Windows Forms Application , so i don't want a console application example .

You could use TcpClient and TcpListener...

Comment: One suggestion would be to use `BeginReceive` and `EndReceive` on the [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) class. Then just call `BeginReceive` again in your callback handler.

Answer (score 3):

I do it like this:

```
void Loop()
{
    TcpListener l = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
    WaitHandle[] h = new WaitHandle[2];
    h[0] = StopEvent;

    WriteInfo("Listening on port {0}", Port);

    l.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        var r = l.BeginAcceptTcpClient(null, null);
        h[1] = r.AsyncWaitHandle;
        // Wait for next client to connect or StopEvent
        int w = WaitHandle.WaitAny(h);
        if (w == 0)  // StopEvent was set (from outside), terminate loop
            break;
        if (w == 1)
        {
            TcpClient c = l.EndAcceptTcpClient(r);

            c.ReceiveTimeout = 90000;
            c.SendTimeout = 90000;

            // client is connected, spawn thread for it and continue to wait for others
            var t = new Thread(ServeClient);
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start(c);
        }
    }
    l.Stop();

    WriteInfo("Listener stopped");
}
```

where `Loop` is started somewhere like that:

```
    StopEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    LoopThread = new Thread(Loop);
    LoopThread.Start();
```

`StopEvent` is used to terminate the listening loop. `ServeClient` serves as the Name indicates a connected client and looks like this:

```
    void ServeClient(object State)
    {
        TcpClient c = (TcpClient)State;

        NetworkStream s = c.GetStream();
        try
        {
             // Communicate with your client
        }
        finally
        {
            s.Close();
            c.Close();
        }
    }
```

this works in any .NET application (Windows Service, Console, WPF or WinForms)

Comment: There's another possibility using asynchronous tcp client / server which I think it's more comfortable. Also for the thread: Use a boolean variable to abort the while-loop. Otherwise you have to quit it forcefully by using Thread.Abort() which is a bad thing. ;)

Good example for async tcp client:
http://robjdavey.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/improved-asynchronous-tcp-client-example/

Comment: Yes , Neurodefekt , i was hoping to see some explanations on async sockets and tcp . Mind sharing some examples here?

Comment: The shown while loop gracefully terminates as soon as the the StopEvent is set. There is no need to abort it. A similar approach could be used to terminate client threads which is not shown here

Comment: @Cofi Have a look at the documentation for [BeginAcceptTcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx) which states: Begins an asynchronous operation to accept an incoming connection attempt.